# Trouble initializing a large matrix Numerical Recipes C++

Tags: c++, matrix, large-data

I'm working in C++. Using Visual Studio 2008, but it is just compiling into a console application (no windows or GUI). The program uses a particular optimization algorithm (dfpmin from Numerical Recipes) that uses a very large matrix of doubles. The matrix it uses is a square matrix that sizes with the parameters.

I have run smaller implementations (where the matrix is about 28,000 X 28,000 and takes up about 6.3 GB) on my machine (8GB RAM 64 bit). Because the required RAM for storing the matrix is pretty hefty, I use the Amazon Elastic Compute service to run it on a virtual machine with more RAM when the matrix is bigger.

I've run the routine when the matrix is on the order of 37,000 X 37,000 (about 11 GB), with a 64 bit virtual machine with 60GB of RAM. However, as the matrix gets bigger still, something goes wrong.

When I set up a problem where the matrix is on the order of 48,000 X 48,0000 (about 18 GB, theoretically) and run it on a 60GB and 120 GB virtual machine, the routine crashes and gives me a c0000005 error that indicates a memory access violation.

Now theoretically, the available RAM on this virtual machine should be more than sufficient to store this matrix.

When I compile the application, it is fine. When I start it up, it is fine. I believe I've tracked the timing of the problem down to this code which is in a header (the main routine calls an object that is defined in the header which performs the optimization).

The optimization object declares a matrix of size nXn, where n is 48,000.

```
 MatDoub hessin(n,n);  // this a matrix of doubles (Numerical recipes has it's own matrix object       MatDoub)
```

The code gets past here, but crashes when it tries to access the matrix to initialize the values as below.

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
for (Int j=0;j<n;j++) {hessin[i][j]=0.0;}
hessin[i][i]=1.0;
}
```

It crashes here the first time that hessin is accessed to write to it, i.e. at hessin[0][0]. I’ve also tried to access hessin[0][0] immediately after the declaration, with the same results.

The indexes don't seem to be running past the end of the array (I've made that error a billion times) because accessing the very first matrix entry [0][0] makes it crash.

It seems like the code allows the creation of the object but then doesn't allow it to be accessed. I haven't yet located the exact value of the size of the matrix at which the code stops working because preparing the data set takes quite a long time.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: `// this a matrix of doubles (Numerical recipes has it's own matrix obj`  I think you need to know exactly how this matrix is implemented, how the memory is allocated, whether the memory has to be one contiguous block, etc.

Comment: Is `hessin` (or the object containing it) static, automatic, or dynamic? What are the details of the exception? Are you checking for allocation failure?

Comment: `The indexes don't seem to be running past the end of the array (I've made that error a billion times) because accessing the very first matrix entry [0][0] makes it crash` No, it looks like new/malloc is returning NULL and when you're trying to dereference it, you're gettin access violation. Try to check result of each and every heap allocation

Comment: I know it's not the best manner to question the original plan, but couldn't or shouldn't you use a sparse matrix? I doubt one gets far with brute force of this size. (or try single precision?)

Comment: If you are using NR's implementation of `MatDoub`, then NR book indicates that "The data space is allocated as a single block". While a 64bit process can in theory allocate much more than you'd need, the guaranteed availability of a very large block of _contiguous_ space is a different story. Tweaking the allocation to use smaller blocks (eg. one for each row), might help.